how to get both name and blob name in http trigger link?
Currently I'm doing http trigger in azure functions, I am able to successfully trigger the function. Below is my code part http trigger.
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

# Retrieve the blob name from the HTTP request
blob_name = req.params.get('blob_name')
if not blob_name:
    return func.HttpResponse(
        "Please provide a 'blob_name' parameter in the query string.",
        status_code=400
    )

here I'm getting blob_name to get my file inside container which is working fine but what I need to do is I want to get both "name" and "blob_name" parameters is it possible to do that? Instead of get() function any other function available to do this.
default function url -

https://functionappname.azurewebsites.net/api/http_trigger?blob_name=file.txt

Now I want it like this

https://functionappname.azurewebsites.net/api/http_trigger?blob_name=file.txt+name=user01


req.params is a dict; you can do a .get() on it to retrieve an element -- you can retrieve name just like you are currently doing with blob_name.
BUT: Your URL format is wrong; instead of + you need to use & to separate the successive parameters.
Instead of
https://functionappname.azurewebsites.net/api/http_trigger?blob_name=file.txt+name=user01
use
https://functionappname.azurewebsites.net/api/http_trigger?blob_name=file.txt&name=user01
I bet that's what's screwing you up.

okay so to get blob_name I used get(blob_name) again in next line I can use same get(name) to get name parameter. Is that what you are saying

In short yes. What you are doing in the URL with this: blob_name=file.txt&name=user01 == You are sending a body. Which automatically becomes available in the "req.params" dict. Hence you can use .get function on the object to get each key:value pair that is sent in the body.
